# Error : Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document' when attempting to click menu options when in a tab

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a application which uses a UI that i purchased (One UI). 
Everything is fine except that when I enter different tabs of my project clicking items on the tab will generate the following errors.

```
 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '/ALLDetails' is not a valid selector.
        at Object.getSelectorFromElement (http://localhost:57386/Content/assets/js/oneui.core.min.js:6:87640)
```

Now various searches on stackoverflow suggest this can occur depending on how the page is called and can be fixed by adding `data-toggle="#"`. However this did not solve my problem.

```
<li class="nav-main-item">
    <a class="nav-main-link nav-main-link-submenu" data-toggle="submenu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
        <i class="nav-main-link-icon si si-wrench"></i>
        <span class="nav-main-link-name">Projects</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav-main-submenu">
        <li class="nav-main-item">
            <a class="nav-main-link" href=@Url.Action("Edit","AllDetails")>
                <span class="nav-main-link-name">Add New Project</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main-item">
            <a class="nav-main-link" href=@Url.Action("Index","AllDetails")>
                <span class="nav-main-link-name">My Projects</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main-item">
            <a class="nav-main-link" data-target="#" href=@Url.Action("SubmittedProp","AllDetails")>
                <span class="nav-main-link-name">Submitted Projects</span>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

Above is the code for one of my menus, it is saved as a partial view and added to my main layout shown below.

```
<div class="content-side content-side-full">
    <ul class="nav-main">

        <li class="nav-main-item">
            <a class="nav-main-link" href=@Url.Action("Index","Home")>
                <span class="nav-main-link-name">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main-heading">All Details</li>
        <li>
            @Html.Partial("_disMenu")
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main-heading">Parameters</li>
        <li>
            @Html.Partial("_disPara")
        </li>
        <li class="nav-main-heading">Logout</li>
        <li>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Logoff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            }
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logoff</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I must again stress that the menu works fine on the home or any other pages but only fails and thows the error when I have entered tabs. 
Any assistance will be greatful and please inform me If there is code i have not posted that should be.

Regards.

Comment: It is very unlikely that someone at StackOverflow may be able to help you here because the error is specific to javascript and you have not posted the relevant code. Looking at your error which points to 'oneui.core.min.js' file, it is advisable for you to connect OneUI support team.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal noted